# RSA encrypt using JSEncrypt and decrypt using BouncyCastle (Java)

Tags: java, typescript, bouncycastle, jsencrypt

This might be a duplicate of [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696854/rsa-encrypt-using-jsencrypt-and-decrypt-using-bouncy-castle), but I can't seem to get the same results. Hoping for some guidance here.

JSEncrypt (client)

```
let encrypt = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(this.publicKey);  // retrieved from server
encrypt.encrypt(password);
```

BouncyCastle (server) - RSA key generation

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pubKey = pair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privKey = pair.getPrivate();

// returned to client
String publicKeyStr = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pubKey.getEncoded()));
String privateKeyStr = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(privKey.getEncoded()));
```

BouncyCastle (server) - Decryption

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
// org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(encrypted.toCharArray()));
decrypted = new String(cipherText, BaseConstant.ENC_UTF8);
```

Error

> org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Illegal hexadecimal character I at index 0
>           at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.toDigit(Hex.java:178)
>           at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(Hex.java:89)

One thing I noticed is the length of encrypted text by JSEncrypt, which is 172, while encryption at server side produces 256.

The answered question mentioned to use RSA/None/PKCS1Padding, which I had already set. What else could I be missing?

Comment: The exception is not related to decryption. The exception is thrown by Hex.decodeHex()

Comment: Thanks, but the solution provided by @Hugo was spot on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs in `Hex.decodeHex()` method, which means that your data is not a Hex encoded string.

`JSEncrypt.encrypt()` method returns the encrypted data in Base64 (instead of Hex string). In order to decrypt it, you must decode it from base64 format.

So instead of:

```
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(encrypted.toCharArray()));
```

Do this:

```
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.toCharArray()));
```

Comment: Great! If it worked and you found it useful, you can upvote and/or accept the answer (it's not mandatory, although a good practice)

Comment: I tried upvoting, but it says I do not have enough reputation points :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem just from the client side. See the code below:

```
let encrypt = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt(); 
encrypt.setPublicKey(this.publicKey);
encrypt.getKey().encrypt(password);
```

Just add `getKey()` after `encrypt`. It worked for me! I encrypted my password into Hex string using this approach.